# How to update a Window.Parent component from inline VF Page

Tags: javascript, inline-visualforce

I know there is a issue in updating Parent component from child componenet due cross site.

But I am wondering, if is there any work around.

I had a Button On click java script code, and I am using those code in my inline visualforce page.

Button code( some part) :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")} 
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; 
function showSimpleDialog(){ 
var recordsIds={!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.OpportunityLineItem)}; 
if(recordsIds.length > 0){ 
var sd = new SimpleDialog("Test"+Dialogs.getNextId(), true); 
sd.setTitle("Update Date Fields"); 
sd.createDialog(); 
window.parent.sd = sd;
```

**Inline VF Page code:**

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; 
                function showSimpleDialog(){                     
                    if(recordsIds.length > 0) { 
                        var sd = new SimpleDialog("Test"+Dialogs.getNextId(), true);

                        sd.setTitle("Update Date Fields"); 

                        sd.createDialog(); 

                        window.parent.sd = sd;
```

But I am facing issue, while assigning `sd` component to `Window.Parent.sd`.

> Invalid access to Parent.

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using easyXDM to trigger the showSimpleDialog call from child and try creating the SimpleDialog in parent  ? Ref: http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/sending-and-receiving-messages/

Comment: @karthikselvakumar : no, actually I didn't know how to use esyXDM :(
Any help ?